# Add pinnedTopRowData in the Detail table "Master / Detail" ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, master-detail

I saw an example that shows how to add PinnedTopRowData:

```
`
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [pinnedTopRowData]="pinnedTopRowData"
      [getRowStyle]="getRowStyle"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (cellEditingStopped)="onCellEditingStopped($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
  `
```

using ag-grid full example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pinned-row-blog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&ref=blog.ag-grid.com.

Is there any way to do the same but implemented in the Master/detail for example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&preview to add a new row in the Detail table?